# Safecracker New Entry already filled out?

Tags: safecracker

On my safecracker form I'm trying to allow each user to add 1 entry to be listed in a directory.  I just created a new account, trying to test the form, but it has the values from the previous account for some reason.  [Heres the form](http://d.pr/i6sk)

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You're using a lot of different calls in the [form](http://d.pr/i6sk) you provided. I'm not certain they are in the proper order. You're calling [Solspace's User](http://www.solspace.com/software/detail/user/), then [Channel Entries](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/index.html), then [Membrr](http://www.membrr.com), then [SafeCracker](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/safecracker/index.html), like so…

```
{exp:user:edit return="member/profile"}

    {exp:channel:entries
    channel="personal_trainer_directory"
    limit="1"
    dynamic="no"
    }

    {if logged_in AND total_entries < 1}

    {exp:membrr:subscribed plan="1003"}

    {exp:safecracker
    channel="personal_trainer_directory"
    return="/member/profile"
    entry_id=""
    safecracker_head="no"
    use_live_url="no"
    url_title=""
    }
```

While other things could also be a factor, say 'cache', I'm wondering about your call order. Solspace's User:Edit form edits the **currently** logged in user, unless you are providing a `member_id` or `username` in the url. You didn't provide a sample url, but let's assume, it's something like:

```
http://mysite.com/directory/personal-trainers/joe-bob
```

That would work for providing 'User' with the identification it needs, but in your next statement…

```
{exp:channel:entries
    channel="personal_trainer_directory"
    limit="1"
    dynamic="no"
    }
```

you turn, dynamic processing off, which means channel:entries **won't** check the 3rd segment for unique identification data, but you aren't telling it what to use as a unique identifier: an `entry_id`, `url_title`, `segment_4`. So I'm not really certain what that statement is doing.

It seems as if you want it to count the number of records entered by the current or provided user, but as is, I think it will always provide *NO* records. Which technically, satisfies your next component…

```
{if logged_in AND total_entries < 1}
```

since 0 is less than 1. I think this may also be your culprit here, because unless you've set-up specific page error trapping, when 'no record' is found using `channel:entries` then the last record entered is displayed.

The other information, looks fine. But I think your problem is in the `channel:entries` statement:

```
{exp:channel:entries
        channel="personal_trainer_directory"
        limit="1"
        dynamic="no"
        }
```

You need to tell it what to check for, so it doesn't just return the last record.

Answer (score 0):

If you are seeing previous form entries it could be caching - check this template isn't cached, clear the cache and try it again.